# How to fix toilet

Tags: toilet, clog

When handle pushed to flushToilet bowl does not overflow but almost completely fill.  Stays that way for long time but eventually drains to a very low level.
     I think it may have started with s clog but plunger doesn't seem to have effect
   What do u do?

Answer (score 1):

I would get a [toilet auger](http://www.lowes.com/pd_24643-72906-40030_0__?productId=999908751&store_code=2940&cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-_-RoughPlumbingElectrical-_-DrainCleaningTools-_-999908751:Cobra&CAWELAID=&kpid=999908751&CAWELAID=320011480006357732&k_clickID=fa0fb43a-ac6f-48c4-99b9-9816966617ff). This is like a short snake for a toilet. It will make sure there is nothing in the toilet trap and at the wax ring. It may help. If you notice the bath tub or shower backing up it is further down the line and a longer snake will be needed. Possibly a plumber to power jet / snake the main line.